# C Language OpenLDAP API for obtaining number of attributes available for a search result entry

Tags: c, ldap, openldap

I want to retrieve the number of attributes available for an LDAP search result entry of type `LDAPMessage` obtained from `ldap_search_ext_s()`. I know it can be done manually by calling `ldap_first_attribute()` and `ldap_next_attribue()` APIs with the help of a loop and a counter variable. But is there any APIs available to obtain the count by a single call?

Comment: There's no standard count operation returning the number of search results without retrieving the results. However some LDAP servers implement custom extensions for that. Which LDAP server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you will have to iterate through the attributes like you say, but some libraries, like the one from IBM have added the `ldap_count_attributes` function: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.glpa100/count_attributes.htm